# How to use dynamic username for postgresql database connection in power bi based on user

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, cube.js

I am using Power BI with [cube.js](https://cube.dev/) as the data source. The connection to Cube is set up using the PostgreSQL connector in Power BI.

I am trying to figure out, how I can change the username, which is being used for the data source connection based on the user who accesses the data in the Power BI service.

The reason is, this allows us the change the security settings dynamically in Cube for each Power BI user.

How can I pass the user email as the username in basic auth for the PostgreSQL connector in Power BI?

Comment: Basic Auth in Power BI means Username/Password.  And you wouldn't have the user's Postgres password.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - Ideally yes, but if that is not possible, I would be okay with just the username.